# CMakeList to generate .cc and .h files from .proto file under a specific folder

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I have the following CMakeList commands in my CMakeLists.txt file and I would like to generate .cc and .h files under `src-gen` folder which is under my main folder, where `src`, `include` and other stuff are. I put the commands to see if they work, but they still get generated outside of `src-gen` folder, so it does not work.

```
include(FindProtobuf)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HEADER} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

set(PROTO_SRC ${PROTO_SRC} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src-gen) #does not work..
set(PROTO_HEADER ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src-gen)#does not work..

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS proto/VisionData.proto)

include_directories(
  ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)

add_executable(cameraSubscriber src/main.cpp ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})

target_link_libraries(cameraSubscriber
   ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

Does anyone know where the mistake is, or what should I add if necessary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This comes from a limitation of `FindProtobuf`. If you look carefully at the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindProtobuf.html) for this module, you find the following line:

> The PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP macro and add_executable() or add_library() calls only work properly within the same directory.

It turns out that the reason why your path setting doesn't work is that you're setting your path relative to `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.3.2/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L131) for this module, you find that the output variables completely ignore the variables you're setting, and writes things into `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`:

```
list(APPEND ${SRCS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc")
list(APPEND ${HDRS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h")
```

The solution I use in my projects is to place all my `.proto` files into one directory, place a `CMakeLists.txt` in that directory specifying the proto build commands. This way you can do `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` on the proto folder, and your `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` will be set appropriately.

This approach also has the benefit of letting you choose the binary directory. I think a call like this will give you the closest thing to what you're asking for. Note the second parameter is assigned to `binary_dir` ([reference here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html)):

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (${PROTO_DIRECTORY} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src-gen)
```

Comment: My `.proto` file is already in a subdirectory called "proto" as you can see in my `CMakeLists.txt`, where I give the path for `.proto` file. However, placing my `CMakeLists.txt" there is not a good idea since then a lot of things will be generated in that proto folder, which has nothing to do with the proto stuff.

Comment: This is the point of my comment. You*have to* put `CMakeLists.txt` in your proto directory. Otherwise your protos will not be generated there. It's just the way this module works. You can always use that `CMakeLists.txt`to only generate protos and generate the rest elsewhere.

Comment: Can I have two CMakeLists.txt, one for generating the protos and other for the rest of the modules I am using?

Comment: That should work. You can generate all other code as you are now, and only generate the protos in the protos directly.